# Can't add anymore fields / blocks to Matrix Field

Tags: templating, matrix, database, limit

I have a really big / flexible Matrix field for one of my websites. It works great and is easy to handle.

The problem is that I need to add another block containing some fields.
I already extenended the `php_value max_input_vars` to `9000`. This worked for a while but I guess I need even more now.

The Matrix field contains **25 blocks** with an average of 5 fields per block as of now but, I need to build another one. If I add another block right now the block will stay but If I add a field to the block and save it, it won't appear when reloading the matrix field.

I know it's alot of blocks inside a matrix field but, it actually is really easy to work with.

Now the question is. **Is there another way to extend the limit or maybe a better solution?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in Craft limiting the amount of Matrix Blocks and fields you can add, it's purely environmental.

The most common values to increase are `max_input_vars`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`, so you'd need to bump one or more of those to higher values to be able to add more.

If you're running things like [Suhosin](https://suhosin.org/stories/index.html) or [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/), they provide their own additional settings that sit on top of php.ini settings that you might need to adjust as well.

Comment: It actually was environmental as you mentioned. Switched to a new local server but somehow it ignored the settings made in the .htaccess file. Had to change it server sided. Thanks for pointing me that way!

Comment: I ran into this same issue today. I added 5 fields and it dropped 3 existing fields. Luckily, I was in a development environment. Is there a way to mitigate losing existing fields or to warn the user of possibly losing fields on the roadmap?

Comment: @kotyy that would be pretty difficult to detect (and be reliable) from PHP.

Comment: @BradBell When saving a Matrix, would serializing the existing fields, appending the newly-created fields reduce the likelihood of dropping an existing field? I noticed in the logs that the POST values were being trimmed from the end. I'd rather lose a new field over an existing field. My two cents.